What is the "restriction of multiplication" by a matrix of a linear transformation, as in this example?
I'm not even sure what this is saying. From the textbook, it seems like R^2 is subspace V and the R^3 is subspace W, or that means T:V->W.

Context of this example: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Lake_Tahoe_Community_College/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/05%3A_Linear_Transformations/5.07%3A_The_Kernel_and_Image_of_A_Linear_Map#:~:text=Consider%20the-,following,-example.

The subspace $V$ is defined as the image of the mapping $T$ so $V$ contains all the vectors $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that can be written as $y=Tx$ for some vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
It turns out that the given mapping is already injective. If we restrict it formally to its image, in the sense that be view $T$ as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $V$, then the mapping is clearly surjective and therefore an isomorphism.
The question now asks you to find a matrix such that the mapping $x \rightarrow Ax$ defined on $V$ (not on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$) is the inverse of $T$.
